# Xamarin TabbedPages MVVM Binding

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

How to bind tabbed page with different view models?
To make it clearer I have this tabbed page:

```
<TabbedPage.Children>     
    <tabPages:Page1/>
    <tabPages:Page2/>
    <tabPages:Page3/>
</TabbedPage.Children>
```

These 3 pages have different view models. However, the problem is the view models of each pages won't bind. Is there a specific way in order to do this?

To test if my view models for each pages works, I inlined the code in tabbed page:
e.g.

```
<TabbedPage.Children>
    <ContentPage Title="Test">
    <Label Text="{Binding TestBind}"/>
    </ContentPage>
</TabbedPage.Children>
```

And for bind it to the view model of the tabbed page (parent) - this method works. However, if I do it separately, the view models wouldn't bind.
E.g.

```
public class Page1ViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
        public Page1ViewModel()
        {
            TestBind = "Test";
        }
        private string _TestBind;
        public string TestBind
        {
            get { return _TestBind; }
            set { SetProperty(ref _TestBind, value); }
        }
}
```

Using it this way, it wouldn't bind

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've made it worked, so this is what I did:

```
  <TabbedPage.Children>
        <views:ChildPage1>
            <views:ChildPage1.BindingContext>
                <viewModels:ChildPage1ViewModel/>
            </views:ChildPage1.BindingContext>
        </views:ChildPage1>
        <views:ChildPage2>
            <views:ChildPage2.BindingContext>
                <viewModels:ChildPage2ViewModel/>
            </views:ChildPage2.BindingContext>
        </views:ChildPage2>
    </TabbedPage.Children>
```

I used binding context property of the element to set it.

Answer (score 3):

Why not just set the BindingContext of each TabPage to each ViewModel:

```
<TabbedPage.Children>     
    <tabPages:Page1 BindingContext="{Binding viewModel1}" />
    <tabPages:Page2 BindingContext="{Binding viewModel2}" />
    <tabPages:Page3 BindingContext="{Binding viewModel3}"/>
</TabbedPage.Children>
```

Those ViewModels would have to exist as properties in the parent VM.

Comment: Then that would mean I would still need to initialize the properties inside each view models into the parent view model? Sorry, but correct me if I am wrong. Thanks